# Slice and coslice categories: duality

Tags: category-theory

I've heard that slice and coslice categories are dual notions. But in what way exactly?

My first idea was to see that $\mathsf{C^{op}}/c = c/\mathsf{C}$ for any object $c$ of a category $\mathsf{C}$, but it doesn't appear to be true.

Comment: $(C^{op}/c)^{op} = c/C$

Comment: @Max equal or equivalent?

Comment: @Max I guess it depends on your choice of foundations. If a morphism between $f\colon x\to c$ and $g\colon y\to c$ is not simply a morphism $h\colon x\to y$ so that the appropriate triangle commutes, but a triple $(f,g,h)$, then the categories in question will only be isomorphic. Of course, it's a technicality, but it's the one we need to the morphisms will have well-defined source and target.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but for categories isomorphism is so rare and so strong (much stronger than equivalence) that I don't mind this abuse of notation

Comment: Just ask yourself where the identity goes: $1_c$ must be terminal in $C/c$, initial in $c/C$.